# JS - Выделение чисел из строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Допустим, дана строка 123x01y88z. Надо, чтобы программа выделила все три отдельных числа (количество чисел может быть любым) и добавила их в массив.
Типа:
[123, 1, 88]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Включая отрицательные и дробные:

```js
let sTxt = `123x-01y8.8z`;
console.log(sTxt.match(/(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/g).map(n => +n));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const str = '123x01y88z';
const result = str.split(/\D+(?!$)/).map(parseFloat);

console.log(result);
```